# Customize the API error response

Tags: magento2, error, api

I need to customize the JSON response of the Magento REST services when an exception is thrown.

Examples:

```
{
    "message": "Request does not match any route.",
    "trace": null
}
```

---

```
{
    "messages": {
        "error": [{"code":500,"message":"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to etc..."}]
    }
}
```

Example unique customization:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "code": 124,
    "message": "Error etc.."
}
```

As you can see Magento has different formats for the exceptions.

Do you known where are the Magento classes to override in my module?

Comment: Please specify your module need and share your custom code so we can help.

Comment: @AdityaShah there is not a custom code or a module, this is a generic question about customizing the built-in API exception of Magento 2, so that I can proceed to create a custom module, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: ohhh lol ohk :d got you :) no need for sorry

Comment: did you find the solution ? or should i post an aswer.

Comment: Was still looking for. I will be glad if you kindly share a solution :)

Comment: Of-cause i will :) made whole custom api so ;)

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: No solutions yet